# Is there a simple way to include library files in MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In building a my application, I have a fairly long list of *.Lib files required for compilation. Here is my compilation instruction:

> Bin\cl.exe Main.cpp /EHsc /I atlmfc\include /I Includes /I Includes\Winsdk atlmfc\lib\amd64\nafxcw.Lib Libs\libcmt.lib Libs\Kernel32.Lib Libs\User32.Lib Libs\Gdi32.Lib Libs\MSImg32.Lib Libs\ComDlg32.Lib Libs\WinSpool.Lib Libs\AdvAPI32.Lib Libs\Shell32.Lib Libs\ComCtl32.Lib Libs\ShLwApi.Lib Libs\Uuid.lib atlmfc\lib\amd64\atls.lib Libs\Ole32.Lib Libs\OleAut32.Lib Libs\oldnames.lib Libs\WS2_32.Lib Libs\MsWSock.Lib Libs\OleAcc.Lib Libs\comsuppw.lib Libs\GdiPlus.lib Libs\Imm32.Lib Libs\WinMM.Lib Libs\MsXml2.Lib Libs\OleDlg.Lib Libs\Urlmon.Lib /link/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS

All of these files are in the same directory. Well, one or two directories anyway. Is there some way that I can just tell the compiler to look in those directories for files that it needs, instead of typing out every single one?

Comment: You have to mention files you need, not just directory to suck all `.LIB`s from. Note that you can also reference the libraries from source code using `#pragma comment(lib, "foo.lib")`

Comment: Use `INCLUDE` and `LIB` environment variables

Comment: @RomanR. I think they should all you to nominate a directory to suck all .Lib files from. There's nothing wrong with it. Stupid they it is not allowed.

Comment: @Jay, I won't use environmental vars cause I like to have my compiler on a USB stick and port it around. Although I suppose I could set the vars in relation to the USB directory structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for http://www.lavishsoft.com/wiki/index.php/Visual_Studio_Paths or [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xhzskbe(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xhzskbe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)? As already explained by Roman R. you can use the pragma command afterwards in your files. This way you can always see which libs are required without looking at the project configuration. If you don't want to use the pragma command there should be a linker section in your project configuration where you can add the libs.

Comment: I don't have Visual Studio installed on my box. Just the SDK's.